# What's the simplest free (or cheap) software to remove unwanted motion in video footage?

Tags: video, software-rec, video-editing, video-capture

I used a program 7 or 8 years ago, that stabilized a video by letting you select a part of the footage that was not supposed to move (like, a sign on a building, or a picture frame on the wall, etc). I remember that the cost was $100, I didn't buy it because my need at that time was very simple and fine for the trial version.

Now I need the same thing again... I would even be willing to pay the $100 bucks for that old program... But I have no idea even what it was called... The old computer that had it on is long gone, along with whatever old version of Adobe Premiere I had at that time. Any clues would be appreciated!

Comment: Ever thought of starting a bounty on this one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen lots of people recommending [Deshaker](http://www.guthspot.se/video/deshaker.htm)

Its a plugin for the FOSS (free in more ways than price) program [VirtualDub](http://www.virtualdub.org/).

It was used to create the example on [WikiPedia's article on digital video stabilisation](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Image_stabilization#Digital_image_stabilization)